# Alternatives to Maven for Java and Scala Development

Tags: java, scala, maven

I've been using Maven for a while for my Java (and now Scala) projects. Recently, I've seen some talk about issue with Maven ([example](http://nealford.com/memeagora/2013/01/22/why_everyone_eventually_hates_maven.html)). Personally, I'm happy with it till now. I've used sbt for Scala a little bit and I think it works well.

Again my point here is not to say which system is better but to expore out what other alternatives exist and how real developers are using them for Java and Scala projects.

Comment: Well you could always use plain old Ant.

Comment: We are a scala shop and we started out with maven because that's what we knew, but we have since switched to SBT.  Maven was not initially built to work with Scala, so you have to tweak it a bit to get it to play nice.  SBT on the other hand was built to work with Scala, so it's really easy to get it to work with your scala projects.  SBT is a bit more complex at times, but it's also less restrictive than maven (allows you do define custom build tasks easily, code builds in scala, etc...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [Scala plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html) for [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).

Alternatively you could use [Scala's built-in Ant tasks](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/98) and [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for dependency management (which is what SBT uses internally).

Yet another option is [Apache Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/).

Pretty much any build system designed for Java-based projects should work with Scala.

**Related:**

- [A Basic Ant+Ivy+Scala Setup](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)
- [Comparing SBT and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061938/comparing-sbt-and-gradle)
- [Buildr vs. Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056186/buildr-vs-gradle-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're going to use Scala, you'll need to become familiar with SBT. It's the standard build system for Scala projects, and the build system of choice at every professional organization that I have worked at using Scala.

SBT has a bit of a learning curve, but it also has some amazing features - console is probably the one I use most - load up a shell with your project already on the CLASSPATH.

You can do some pretty clever stuff with SBT - in the end it's all Scala under the hood. The effort to pick it up is well worth it if you plan to work with Scala professionally.